# How do you recive TCP data through sockets

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, tcpclient

I am working on a project in which I need to send and receive data between a mobile iOS device and essentially a computer. Thus far I have code that will send data from an iOS device to a computer but I can not figure out how to receive data from computer to iOS device. I am looking for some advice/code to do so. I will post parts of my code that are needed to understand what I have set up this far.

```
- (void)setup {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:host];

    NSLog(@"Setting up connection to %@ : %i", [url absoluteString], port);

   // CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)[url host], port, &readStream, &writeStream);
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, @"localhost", port, &readStream, &writeStream);

    if(!CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream)) {
        NSLog(@"Error, writeStream not open");

        return;
    }
    [self open];

    NSLog(@"Status of outputStream: %lu", (unsigned long)[outputStream streamStatus]);
    return;
}

- (void)open {
    NSLog(@"Opening streams.");

    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream retain];
    [outputStream retain];

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)event {
    NSLog(@"Stream triggered.");

    switch(event) {
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
            if(stream == outputStream) {
                NSLog(@"outputStream is ready.");
            }
            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            if(stream == inputStream) {
                NSLog(@"inputStream is ready.");

                uint8_t buf[1024];
                unsigned int len = 0;

                len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];

                if(len > 0) {
                    NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

                    [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];

                    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    [self readIn:s];

                    [data release];
                }
            } 
            break;
        }
        default: {
            NSLog(@"Stream is sending an Event: %i", event);

            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)writeOut:(NSString *)s {
    uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t *)[s UTF8String];
    [self open];
    [outputStream write:buf maxLength:strlen((char *)buf)];

    NSLog(@"Writing out the following:");
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

I run the setup code and I run the write code and everything works great. I just now need to receive data from computer to iOS as stated above.

Comment: It would be easier to implement 3rd party library like SocketRocket. They're really good and easy to use.

Comment: how would you install that on Xcode?

Comment: Basically we install it on our project. Not on xcode itself. To install it either u use cocoapods or simply drag and drop the library into ur project.

Comment: i understand that much but like i can't find a link to install it everything wants me to use cocoapods

Comment: Goto https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket and click Download. Then you just copy the SocketRocket folder into your project. Add the relevant frameworks and then you can import "SocketRocket.h" to use it.

Comment: ok, i appreciate the help! any examples of sending and receiving TCP data?

Comment: so i just downloaded and added socket rocket to Xcode as you stated above and when I build the project i get a bunch of import issues with the socketRocket code itself

Comment: Have you tried imported the relevant frameworks? Like Security, Foundation? If you done that but still getting errors, I highly suggest you install cocoapods. It makes your life easier to use any 3rd party lib.

Comment: Got socket rocket working now just need some examples. Looking through theirs I have no clue how to even set up a connection.